# How can I add "border" in the Owl carousel navigation button(around next & previous)

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider, owl-carousel

How can I add a border around Next and also Previous buttons in the Owl Carousel slider like in this picture?

Image- [image: owl-carousel navigation border]

I have tried but not working

```css
    .blog-active .owl-nav button {
        position: absolute;
        top: -82px;
        left: 190px;
        color: black;
        background: red;
        height: 40px;
        width: 40px;
        line-height: 40px;
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-radius: 50%;
        text-align: center;
    }
```

Comment: inspect the element, find ID or class name and set it in CSS.  [HERE](https://www.freakyjolly.com/owl-carousel-2-customize-navigation-next-prev-arrows/#.X-tW19hKj-g) is a good example.

Comment: i have done by inspecting these things but where is the problem?

Comment: Have you tried `!important` ?  Like `border: 1px solid #000 !important;`

Comment: Thanks a lot, bro!!, Working now after adding "!important".

Comment: Glad that solved it.  I've made an answer .. Please feel free to "accept" my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The styling for OWL is created after the DOM is rendered using JavaScript.  Therefore you'll need to use `!important` to make sure that your style aren't overwritten at the time of render.  IE

```
border: 1px solid #000 !important;
```